# Problem updating a record that has an association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not able to update a record that has an association in Rails.

For example, I have a `Post` model and a `User` model. In post.rb I've included the association `belongs_to :user`.

If I want to change the user_id field for an existing Post record, it doesn't work.

```
p = Post.find(1)
p.user_id = 5
p.save
```

The above doesn't change the Post record's user_id field to 5. When I remove the association, the above code works.

Is there a way to update the user_id field without removing the association?

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: This should work, though it's unusual to assign an ID directly. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Does the user with id=5 exists?

Comment: Yes, the user with the id 5 does exist. And I don't get an error message. When I try this in the console, it says true. But the user_id doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> These examples look like they should work but for some reason the user_id remains unchanged. Maybe it has something to do with the validations

You can easily verify if it's due to validations by replacing `"save"` with `"save!"`

The former just returns false if any of the validations fail, whereas the latter will raise an exception:

```
p = Post.find(1)
p.user = User.find(5)
p.save!
```

Alternatively, you can also do the following in a Rails console:

```
>> p = Post.find(1)
...
>> p.user = User.find(5)
...
>> p.valid?
... 
>> # will be either true or false, depending on validations
>> p.errors.full_messages
... 
>> # will be either [] or else a non-empty array of all validation failures
>> _
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" way to do this is to let Rails do all the heavy-lifting, as follows:

```
p = Post.find(1)
p.user = User.find(5)
p.save
```

... which will work, assuming all validations are met.

Alternatively:

```
Post.find(1).update_attribute(:user_id, 5)
```

... although you probably want to think twice before using the latter!  :-)

Peter

Comment: Thanks for the answer. These examples look like they should work but for some reason the user_id remains unchanged. Maybe it has something to do with the validations